# capturin an iframe creation even from external source

Tags: javascript, iframe, lightbox

I am using a third-party SomeScript.js, which is producing an iframe on my page after I click a special button ("special" meaning it has to have a particular id). The process appears simple - "lightbox integration" do they call it - you click the special button, the iframe with mildly sophisticated inputs on a form appears. The problem is, this iframe doesn't have focus. I have found whole articles about how to set a focus on an iframe that *you* create programmatically in you code. But this isn't the case here. As the 'lightbox' has no focus, it is a bad user experience.

I thought of adding a timeout to the button click, and then search for the newly generated iframe to set the focus, but as I don't control the timing of it's appearance, I wonder if there's some other approach.

Thanks all!

Comment: You need to add a `MutationObserver` your DOM, this will trigger when the watched part of the DOM changes (i,.e. your iFrame is added) from there you can set focus. [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Thanks mate, that's what I expected - just lacked the keyword, "monitor", huh. I thought maybe there's some "iframe event" already existed in the world ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demo, referencing the sample code here: [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
const addSomeThing = () => {};

// Copied from MDN demo.
const whenSomethingHappens = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
      // This is where we will see our new iFrame.
      
    } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Start watching our DOM. 
  const targetNode = document.querySelector("#watchme");
  
  // Mutation Config.
  const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
  
  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(whenSomethingHappens);

  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);

 //Lets add something in 5secs. 
 setTimeout(() => { 
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = 'Testing';
  document.querySelector('#watchme').appendChild(el);
 }, 5000);
 

});
```

```html
<div id="watchme">Here is where we will add</div>
```